# Bash script: only echo line to ~/.bash_profile once if the line doesn't yet exist

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sed, grep

I wrote a [bash git-install script](http://www.mattdipasquale.com/blog/2010/05/30/instructions-how-to-install-git-from-source-on-mac-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard-intel-x86-32-bit/). Toward the end, I do:

```
echo "Edit ~/.bash_profile to load ~/.git-completioin.bash on Terminal launch"
echo "source ~/.git-completion.bash" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

The problem is, if you run the script more than once, you end up appending this line multiple times to ~/.bash_profile. How do I use bash scripting with `grep` or `sed` (or another option you may recommend) to only add the line if it doesn't yet exist in the file. Also, I want to add the line to `~/.profile` if that file exists and `~/.bash_profile` doesn't exist, otherwise just add it to `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Be careful about race conditions with this -- if you might have two instances of the script running at once, they could both append to the file; to avoid that you'd want to guard the section with flock. Prolly not a biggie for this specific use case, but might be an important consideration to keep in mind when applying the same techniques for other purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if [[ ! -s "$HOME/.bash_profile" && -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] ; then
  profile_file="$HOME/.profile"
else
  profile_file="$HOME/.bash_profile"
fi

if ! grep -q 'git-completion.bash' "${profile_file}" ; then
  echo "Editing ${profile_file} to load ~/.git-completioin.bash on Terminal launch"
  echo "source \"$HOME/.git-completion.bash\"" >> "${profile_file}"
fi
```

Answer (score 11):

Something like this should do it:

```
LINE_TO_ADD=". ~/.git-completion.bash"

check_if_line_exists()
{
    # grep wont care if one or both files dont exist.
    grep -qsFx "$LINE_TO_ADD" ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile
}

add_line_to_profile()
{
    profile=~/.profile
    [ -w "$profile" ] || profile=~/.bash_profile
    printf "%s\n" "$LINE_TO_ADD" >> "$profile"
}

check_if_line_exists || add_line_to_profile
```

A couple of notes:

- I've used the `.` command instead of `source` as `source` is a bashism, but `.profile` may be used by non-bash shells. The command `source ...` is an error in `.profile`
- I've used `printf` instead of `echo` because it's more portable and wont screw up backslash-escaped characters as bash's `echo` would.
- Try to be a little more robust to non-obvious failures. In this case make sure .profile exists *and is writable* before trying to write to it.
- I use `grep -Fx` to search for the string. `-F` means fixed strings, so no special characters in the search string needs to be escaped, and `-x` means match the whole line only. The `-qs` is common grep syntax for just checking the existence of a string and not to show it.
- This is proof of concept. I didn't actually run this. My bad, but it's Sunday morning and I want to go out and play.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
grep -q '^source ~/\.git-completion\.bash$' ~/.bash_profile || echo "source ~/.git-completion.bash" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

or in a more explicit (and readable) form:

```
if ! grep -q '^source ~/\.git-completion\.bash$' ~/.bash_profile; then
    echo "Updating" ~/.bash_profile

    echo "source ~/.git-completion.bash" >> ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

EDIT:

You should probably add an additional newline before your one-liner, just in case `~/.bash_profile` does not end in one:

```
if ! grep -q '^source ~/\.git-completion\.bash$' ~/.bash_profile; then
    echo "Updating" ~/.bash_profile

    echo >> ~/.bash_profile   
    echo "source ~/.git-completion.bash" >> ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

EDIT 2:

This is a bit easier to modify and slightly more portable:

```
LINE='source ~/.git-completion.bash'

if ! grep -Fx "$LINE" ~/.bash_profile >/dev/null 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "Updating" ~/.bash_profile

    echo >> ~/.bash_profile   
    echo "$LINE" >> ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

The `-F` and `-x` options are specified by POSIX and were suggested in several other answers and comments.

Comment: I'd use `grep -F` rather than using a standard regular-expression grep statement which needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Decide which profile to add to
PROFILE=~/.bash_profile
if ! [ -e "$PROFILE" ] && [ -e ~/.profile ]; then
    PROFILE=~/.profile
fi

# Add to profile if it doesn't appear to be there already. Err on the side of
# not adding it, in case user has made edits to their profile.
if ! grep -s 'git-completion\.bash' "$PROFILE"; then
    echo "Editing $PROFILE to load ~/.git-completion.bash on Terminal launch"
    echo "source ~/.git-completion.bash" >> "$PROFILE"
fi
```